# Проблема с использованием uniform mat4 в GLSL-шейдере в туториале по OpenGL

Tags: glsl, шейдеры, c++, opengl

Есть код, который рисует на экране треугольник. Есть 2 vertex shader и общий fragment shader. Первый vertex shader просто указывает координаты вершины - он работает:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main(){
     gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
     gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

Вот второй:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){
    vec4 v = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1); 
    gl_Position.xyzw = MVP * v;
}
```

MVP - матрица 4x4 отправленная в шейдер из кода c++. Вот создание и отправка матрицы:

```
mat4 Projection = perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);

mat4 View = lookAt(vec3(4, 3, 3),
                   vec3(0, 0, 0),
                   vec3(0, 1, 0)
);

mat4 Model = mat4(1.0f);

mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;

GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");

glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);
```

В процессе создания шейдера проверяется состояние на каждом этапе компиляции. 
Нет никаких ошибок и все компилируется. Однако, наблюдается пустой экран. В чем причина? Может в инициализации glew/glfw3? Делал все по учебнику. Вот сайт туториала по [OpenGL](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/). Нужный кусок в самом конце. Использую glew 1.10.0, glfw 3.0.4. Видео - NVIDIA gt 750m (драйвер - 337.88), OS - Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел проблему! Все оказалось очень прозаично. Вызов glUseProgram(programID) должен предшествовать glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]), так как вызов последней должен быть связан с текущим шейдером. Если делать наоборот, как я сделал, openGL не выводит геометрии вовсе.